# Calculated Formula on Column not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

```
=IF([First Date]>0,0.15,IF([Second Date]>0,0.3,IF([Third Date]>0,0.45,IF([Fourth Date]>0,0.6,IF([Fifth Date]>0,0.75,IF([Sixth Date]>0,0.9,IF([Seventh Date]>0,1,0)))))))
```

This is the formula I am using to determine a rough percentage for a calculated column that is looking at whether 7 dates have been entered - so for example if date 5 has been entered it is 75%, or if date 6 has been entered it is 90%

It only seems to return the value of the first date - 15% even when date 2 or 3 etc have been entered. Any ideas?

Comment: try reversing conditions from date 7 to date 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing conditions from Seventh Date to First Date like:

```
=IF([Seventh Date]>0,1,IF([Sixth Date]>0,0.9,IF([Fifth Date]>0,0.75,IF([Fourth Date]>0,0.6,IF([Third Date]>0,0.45,IF([Second Date]>0,0.3,IF([First Date]>0,0.15,0)))))))
```

You can also use `ISBLANK([Date Column Name])` to check if date column is blank or not.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Thank you Ganesh! The reversing did the trick :)